# scope issue in angular template, cannot render object data despite showing up in devtools console.log --- express nodejs knex postgreSQL backend

Tags: scope, controller

This is my Dashboard Controller that I have linked up to two templates with ngRoute. On the first template (agent-dashboard) I use ng-repeat to display my table data. There I click on an artist name to direct to another template.

My console.log($scope.eachArt); shows up in Chrome DevTools with the desired object information and I am trying to render it using something like {{ eachArt.artist_name  }} . For some reason that I am not able to determine I cannot grab and display this object data on the second template I am linking to from the first.

```
'use strict';


(function(){
  var AgentDashboard = function ($scope, $http, $location) {

    $scope.greeting = "Welcome to your ";
    $scope.pageID = "Agent Dashboard Page ";

    $scope.fetchArtist = function() {
      // console.log(id);
      $http.get('/getArtist/').then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data);

        $scope.artistData = result.data;
      })
    }
    $scope.accessIndiv = function(artist_id) {
      $http.get('/getArtist/' + artist_id).then((data) => {
        $scope.eachArt = data.data[0];
        console.log($scope.eachArt);
        var path = $location.path('/indv-art');


      })
    }

  }
  angular.module('avp')
  .controller('AgentDashboard', AgentDashboard);
    AgentDashboard.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location'];
}())
```

Comment: do you have the console.log output?

Comment: Yes. I ended up resolving the issue with $rootScope

Answer (score 0):

used $rootscope although it would be smarter to have used a factory or a service. Duct Tape Code for the win on a deadline!